# Snap code error

Tags: debian, kali-linux, snap

Im trying to instal Vcode++ on linux, but it needs snap.
was installing "sudo snap install --classic code"

But im getting this error.
"error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/code": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory".

how can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What Linux distribution? And it is native, not Ubuntu or other running in WSL? Is snapd running?

Comment: you've tagged this [tag:kali-linux], but you're definitely trying to do something that Kali simply isn't meant for, and it's making your life hard. Read Kali's own explanation of why you shouldn't be using Kali: https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1.`service snapd start`

2.`sudo systemctl start snapd.service`

3.`sudo snap install --classic code`

If the output of the first command is as follows,

```
snapd.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)  
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

then run the following command and after doing so, run the 3 commands mentioned above.

`sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service`